# Continuity of generalised Legendre transform

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, convex-analysis, optimal-transportation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be $\sigma$-compact spaces, and $\mu$ [resp. $\nu$] be a regular Borel probability measure on $X$ [resp. $Y$].

For a bounded continuous $c:X\times Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we consider the *$c$-transform*
$$\tag{1}
T_c \, : \, L^1(\mu) \,\ni\, \varphi \,\mapsto\, \varphi^c, \quad\text{where}\quad \varphi^c(y):= \inf_{x\in X} c(x,y) - \varphi(x)
$$

(as known e.g. from the theory of optimal transport). Let $\varphi\in L^1(\mu)$ and $(\varphi_\alpha)\subset L^1(\mu)$ be a net.

My **question** is: If $\varphi, (\varphi_\alpha)\in C_b(X)$ with $\varphi_\alpha\rightarrow\varphi$ uniformly on compact sets, does this imply that $T_c(\varphi_\alpha)\rightarrow T_c(\varphi)$ in $L^1(\nu)$ ?

Any hints or references are welcome.

Comment: (i) $T_c$ will never be from $L^1(\mu)$ to $L^1(\nu)$. (ii) According to MathOverflow [guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-answer), users should avoid answering multiple questions asked in one post. Please remove one of the two questions in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\vpi\varphi$The answer is no. E.g., suppose that $X=Y=\mathbb R$, $c=0$, and $\vpi_a(x)=\min(a,\max(0,x-a))$ for $a\ge0$ and all real $x$. Then, as $a\to\infty$, we have $\vpi_a\to0$ uniformly on compact sets, whereas $T_c(\vpi_a))=-a\not\to0=T_c(0)$ in $L^1(\nu)$ for any probability measure $\nu$ over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @rmcerafl : At this point, I don't know an answer concerning the stronger convergence. You may want to post that question in a separate post.

Comment: Said question has now been posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451601/generalised-lebesgue-transform-continuous-wrt-strict-topology).